# Angular Universal - unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, angular, nginx, angular-universal

Working URL http://example.com:4200/signin 
Not working URL http://example.com/signin

I have also added base href in index.html file

```
<base href="/">
```

nginx configuration -

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    location / {
        root /home/bitnami/apps/app_name/dist/browser;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4200;
        try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ $uri/ /index.html;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

server.ts

```
// Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine)
app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
  bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory,
  providers: [
    provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
  ]
}));

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser'));

/* - Example Express Rest API endpoints -
  app.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
*/

// Server static files from /browser
app.get('*.*', express.static(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser'), {
  maxAge: '1y'
}));

// ALl regular routes use the Universal engine
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', { req });
});

// Start up the Node server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

Can someone help me out what is wrong here?

Comment: I don't see how your question's title correlates with your error. Can you explain that?

Comment: on the production server after deployment, not working without port number(4200). It gives above error.

Comment: Hey @NileshMistry did you solve the issue? If yes, can you explain the solution, thanks.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with Angular 8 + Universal. Has somebody solved this? I've been trying for a few days but keep getting errors such as "The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of text/html" or "Unexpected token <"